# PayPal NVP Partial refunds refunding full amount

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-nvp

PayPal NVP Partial refunds refunding full amount though specified the RefundType as "Partial"

Here is the request i am using

```
    public string Refund_Partial(string transactionID, string refundType,string Amount)
    {
        string strCredentials = "USER=" + strUsername + "&PWD=" + strPassword + "&SIGNATURE=" + strSignature;
        string strNVP = strCredentials;
        strNVP += "&METHOD=RefundTransaction&VERSION=" + strAPIVersion;

        strNVP += "&TRANSACTIONID=" + transactionID + "&REFUNDTYPE=" + refundType + "¤cy=USD" + "&AMOUNT=" + Amount;
        //Create web request and web response objects, make sure you using the correct server (sandbox/live)
        HttpWebRequest wrWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strNVPSandboxServer);
        //Set WebRequest Properties
        wrWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        // write the form values into the request message
        StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(wrWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
        requestWriter.Write(strNVP);
        requestWriter.Close();
        // Get the response.
        HttpWebResponse hwrWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wrWebRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(wrWebRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        // and read the response
        string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        responseReader.Close();
        return responseData;
    }
```

Can anyone please let me know do i need to include more parameters to do a partial refund?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change the Parameters value for currencyCode and Amount, From

```
"¤cy=USD" + "&AMOUNT=" + Amount
```

to

```
"CURRENCYCODE=USD" + "&AMT=" + Amount
```

Have a look at [RefundTransaction API Operation (NVP)](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/refundtransaction-api-operation-nvp).

May be PayPal is looking for `AMT` parameter which is not there, which is why it is refunding in Full